# Recommendations for hooking Java into MS Exchange Server

Tags: java, exchange-server

At my current job we are using a product called JINTEGRA that lets us get access to users outlook folders (Contacts, email, calendar etc.) and make updates through a separate CDO/MAPI server.

I was wondering if anyone could recommend any alternatives to this ? We had initially tried WEBDAV which was good for reading information, but not writing.

JINTEGRA has an annoying licensing model that is constantly firing off license violations and requires us to manage separate licensed jars for every server and developer so we are looking to get away from them.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

1. you can consume Exchange Web Services (starting with Exchange 2007 I think) with jax-ws for example or any other webservice tool. We do this but we consume them from .net too
2. you can use javamail and access exchange via IMAP, but you don't have access to all items (Contacts etc), if you just need mails this is fine though (we do this too)
3. there are some opensource projects but never used them so cannot vouch for them, one is http://sourceforge.net/projects/j-xchange/